# Issue with Category tree in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, tree, twig, categories

I created a Category Tree in symfony 5

I've following:

Category.php Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent")
 */
private $children;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getParent(): ?self
{
    return $this->parent;
}

public function setParent(?self $parent): self
{
    $this->parent = $parent;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|self[]
 */
public function getChildren(): Collection
{
    return $this->children;
}

public function addChild(self $child): self
{
    if (!$this->children->contains($child)) {
        $this->children[] = $child;
        $child->setParent($this);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

CategoryReponsitory.php

```
public function getAllCategory()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.parent IS NULL');

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Controller.php

```
public function index(CategoryRepository $categoryRepository): Response
{
    return $this->render('category/index.html.twig', [
        'categories' => $categoryRepository->getAllCategory(),
    ]);
}
```

And the twig template file `index.html.twig`

```
{% macro menu_categories(categories) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        <li>
            <a href="cate/{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% if category.children %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ macros.menu_categories(category.children) }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

<ul class="menu-category">
    {{ _self.menu_categories(categories) }}
</ul>
```

It render is correctly, But if the children don't have any children, it still renders html like image bellow:

[image]

I don't want it, for some reason. How can I fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior for collections seems to be different than for arrays. Since `children` is an `ArrayCollection` it'll always be set. You should check if it contains elements.

```
{% if category.children is not empty %}
    <ul class="children">
        {{ macros.menu_categories(category.children) }}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```